# Eloquent Laravel: How to select specific columns based on a value in related table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to get different fields based on the value from another column using Eloquent.

I have two tables **project** and **project_jobs**.

I have a relationship between them like this

```
public function job_overview()
{
   return $this->hasOne(ProjectJob::class)->oldestOfMany();
}
```

I'm pulling Projects and relationships with the following code

```
$projects = Project::select($project_fields)
   ->with(['job_overview]);
```

Obviously, this gives me all the fields within the Project Jobs table

Project Jobs table looks like this

| Id | type | column A | column B | column C | column D | column E | column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | floor |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | roof |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I want to select column A,B,C when type is floor and column D,E,F when type is roof.

Is it possible to validate job_overview.type in a when condition? Something like this

```
$projects = Project::select($project_fields)
   ->with(['job_overview])
   ->when('job_overview' ....);
```

Or what is the best way to select different columns from the project_jobs table based on the type value?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE WHEN` in the SQL query that is executed for the `job_overview` relationship.

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN type = "floor" THEN columnA
        WHEN type = "roof" THEN columnD
        ELSE "invalid"
    END AS column_a_or_d,
    CASE
        WHEN type = "floor" THEN columnB
        WHEN type = "roof" THEN columnE
        ELSE "invalid"
    END AS column_b_or_e,
    CASE
        WHEN type = "floor" THEN columnC
        WHEN type = "roof" THEN columnF
        ELSE "invalid"
    END AS column_c_or_f
FROM project_jobs
```

```php
$projects = Project::query()
    ->select($project_fields)
    ->with([
        'job_overview' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(
                'project_id', /* making sure the foreign key is selected is necessary for eloquent to work. */
                DB::raw('CASE WHEN type = "floor" THEN columnA WHEN type = "roof" THEN columnD ELSE "invalid" END AS column_a_or_d'),
                DB::raw('CASE WHEN type = "floor" THEN columnB WHEN type = "roof" THEN columnE ELSE "invalid" END AS column_b_or_e'),
                DB::raw('CASE WHEN type = "floor" THEN columnC WHEN type = "roof" THEN columnF ELSE "invalid" END AS column_c_or_f')
            );
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```